# Adobe AIR 20+ doesn't run with GPU rendermode on Androids using Nvidia GPUs?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Adobe AIR 20+ doesn't run with GPU rendermode on Androids using Nvidia GPUs?

I have tried installing a completely blank and clean "app" with nothing on it.

When I select GPU rendermode with the Adobe AIR 20.x.x.x or higher SDK then this test app WILL NOT run on Nvidia Shield or similar devices using Nvidia GPU.

If I switch to Adobe AIR 19.x.x.x then it runs fine...

Any one have any idea whats up?

Comment: Does `direct` mode work?

Comment: what are you using "gpu" mode for ? good mobile graphics performance may only be achieved with "direct" mode, using Stage3D api (hardware-accelerated). If you want only hardware-accelerated 2D, a 2D framework like Starling will make the transition easier. If performance is not an issue, then I think any (working) mode will do the trick. I would say that "gpu" mode is almost deprecated, that's why it was not properly tested on latest SDK version

Comment: you can have a look at the list of bugs affecting rendermode "gpu":https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=search&product=1975&title=gpu

Comment: Official anwser by Adobe is :"Note: In order to leverage GPU acceleration of Flash content with AIR for mobile platforms, Adobe recommends that you use renderMode="direct" (that is, Stage3D) rather than renderMode="gpu". Adobe officially supports and recommends the following Stage3D based frameworks: Starling (2D) and Away3D (3D). For more details on Stage3D and Starling/Away3D, see http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/." http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html

Comment: @jauboux Actually, GPU render mode gives you great performance, in some cases better than stage 3d, when used "correctly', and it gives you the luxuries of the classic display list. It's a shame that Adobe hasn't pushed it further. Of course, since Adobe made that decision, Stage3D is unfortunately the only "smart" option going forward. Starling does make this easier, but only GPU render mode lets you use the Flash timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s a known bug in AIR SDK 20 : https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4110662

I don't see another solution than hold on to AIR SDK 19, add your vote to the bug, post additional info if relevant, and wait for it to be fixed.